# При цене = 0, изменить текст кнопки "Добавить в корзину"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, интернет-магазин

При цене товара = 0, нужно поменять текст кнопки "Добавить в корзину" на "Запросить стоимость".

Написал такой код с условиями. Но он крашит ВордПресс.

```
function my_theme_cart_button_text() {
    return 'Запросить стоимость';
    }


function nulled_price_call ($product) {
    if ($product -> get_price() == 0) {
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'my_theme_cart_button_text' );
}
}

nulled_price_call();
```

Я новичок в php, буду рад вашей помощи

Answer (score 1):

вы можете это сделать вот так

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );

function woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text( $btn_text, $product ) {
    return $product->get_price() ? $btn_text : __( 'Запросить стоимость', 'woocommerce' );
}
```